# React.useState re-renders with wrong state

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component, use-state

I have the following reduced code that controls my dashboard

```js
function App(props){
    const [role, setRole] = React.useState("guest");
    const [componentDrawerRender, setComponentDrawerRender] = React.useState(null);

    const handleSelectionDrawerClick = (component) => {

        setComponentDrawerRender(component);
        handleOpenComponentDrawer(true);
    };

    const handleLoginCallback = (user) => {

        if (user !== false) {
          handleCloseComponentDrawer();
          setRole(user.type);    <-- setting the new state does not work 
          console.log(val.type + " -> " + role );   <-- this here shows != values

        } else {
          //do nothing
        }
      };

    return (  
        <Button
        onClick={() => {
          handleSelectionDrawerClick(
            <LoginPage callback={handleLoginCallback} />
          );
        }}
      >
        LOG IN
      </Button>);
}
```

The purpose of this code is to open a drawer (which it does), render a component in the drawer(which it does), and after the user logs in with the component close the drawer (which it does) and update the state(which it almost does).

The problem occurs within the `handleLoginCallback` method. Good data is sent back and the state is updated with good data. However only some components on the page are updated.

**How does the re-render process work for functional components? does it just call the function again or does it only somehow recompute the return value? The following code is not re-computed on the re-render. Is it ok to have some states depend on other states?**

```js
const [mainList, setMainList] = React.useState((role) => {
    console.log(role);
    if (role === undefined || role === null) {
      return GuestListItems(handleSelectionDrawerClick);
    } else if (role === "customer") {
      return CustomerListItems;
    } else {
      return OwnerListItems;
    }
  });
```

below is the code in the `<LoginPage>` that calls the callback method.

```js
onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    this.props.login(this.state, this.handleLoadingBar).then((retState) => {
      if(retState === null){
        this.props.callback(false);       <-- here 
      }else {
        this.props.callback(retState);    <-- here 
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    this.props.login(this.state, this.handleLoadingBar).then((retState) => {
      if(retState === null){
        this.props.callback(false);       <-- here 
      }else {
        this.props.callback(retState);    <-- here 
      }
    });
  }
```

You're setting the initial state of this to a function no to the result of the function.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `role` value is updated on the subsequent refresh (i.e. function call), because the `setRole` invocation. There are a couple of reasons because role does not change at the `console.log` line:

1. the `role` is marked as const;
2. JavaScript does not run any other function until the current one finishes (better: the call stack gets empty).

Check this also: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

The `useState` hook is a normal function which gets an argument, and returns a tuple. Despite the hook (and thus the argument) is called on every single refresh, the argument value is used only at the very first initialization.

Here is the API description: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate

Comment: why does the state not get updated for them `mainList` then?

Comment: do you mean the `mainList` const is not initialized on the very first pass? Honestly, I don't understand you questions about the 2nd snippet.